# failed to resolve implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle is not syncing properly, getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6LHz.png).

Help me to resolve this error when i add this library and press sync now it show this error (Failed to resolve).

Help me please to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

You must add `build.gradle`

```
repositories { maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven" } }
```

reference: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1985 and https://github.com/kmenager/material-animated-switch

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code on gradlle(Project) all projects

```
maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
    }
```

In the end, it will look something like this

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      maven {
          url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
      }
   }
}
```